# error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 255

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, kinect, openframeworks

I got this error while im trying to execute kinectexample in openframeworks in visual studio 2017

2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(138,5): error MSB3073: The command "for /d %%f in (C:\Program Files (x86)\of_v0.10.1_vs2017_release\libs\openFrameworksCompiled\project\vs\........\libs*) do (if exist %%f\lib\vs\Win32*.dll ( robocopy "%%f\lib\vs\Win32" "C:\Program Files (x86)\of_v0.10.1_vs2017_release\examples\computer_vision\kinectExample\bin" "*.dll" /njs /njh /np /fp /bytes ))
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(138,5): error MSB3073: if errorlevel 1 exit 0 else exit %errorlevel%
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(138,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 255.

Comment: Check your custom build step(s) on that project. It looks like one of them is failing, and thus failing your build.

Comment: This has nothing to do with C++. A shell command is failing. You need to take this up with the developers on the project. https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/issues